# TaskScheduler with limited concurrency blocks itself

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am trying to use [the following custom task scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to limit concurrent web requests:

I'm using it like this:

```
const int CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 2;

static void Main()
{
    TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(CONCURRENCY_LEVEL));

    Task.WaitAll(new[] { factory.StartNew(() => SomeAction("first")), factory.StartNew(() => SomeAction("second")) });

    Console.WriteLine("All tasks ended");        
    Console.Read();
}

static void SomeAction(string task)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task + " task started");
    Console.WriteLine(AnotherTask(task).Result);
    Console.WriteLine(task + " task ended");
}

static async Task<string> AnotherTask(string task)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(task + " inner task started");
        // imitate web requests
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(task + " inner task ended");
        return "ok";
    });
}
```

The problem is that the inner tasks are using my `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` instead of the default `TaskScheduler`. This leads to self blocking and the output is like this:

```
second task started
first task started
first inner task started
second inner task started
second inner task ended
first inner task ended
```

When I change the `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL` to `3` or change the `factory` to `Task.Factory` then obviously everything is working fine and the output is like:

```
first task started
second task started
first inner task started
second inner task started
second inner task ended
first inner task ended
ok
second task ended
ok
first task ended
All tasks ended
```

I **cannot** change the code in `SomeAction`. What else can I do? Is there a bug in the Microsoft sample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify `TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler` when starting tasks from your custom task scheduler:

```
Task.WaitAll(new[] 
{
   factory.StartNew(() => SomeAction("first"),  TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler), 
   factory.StartNew(() => SomeAction("second"), TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler)
});
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `HideScheduler` Prevents the ambient scheduler from being seen as the current scheduler in the created task. This means that operations like `StartNew` or `ContinueWith` that are performed in the created task will see `Default` as the current scheduler.

Comment: Yes! :) This is the perfect solution for my case, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
static async Task<string> AnotherTask(string task)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(task + " inner task started");
        // imitate web requests
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(task + " inner task ended");
        return "ok";
    }).ConfigureAwait(false); //<--------
}
```

Comment: yes, It's working but as I mentioned - I cannot change this piece of code. This is a `HttpClient`'s internal task in real code and I don't have the possibility to change its creation options

Comment: @Adassko I don't get you! why can't you do `httpclient.GetSomeAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false); `

Comment: Because it's not my piece of code - I'm only invoking it. This is from external plugin library and I would like my code to be able to run any type of code without blocking

Comment: @Adassko your external library should have used `.ConfigureAwait(false); ` It can not assume whether you want want to sync it with your working thread or not. A bad coding.

Comment: @Adassko BTW: you say "*I cannot change the code in SomeAction*" and my change is in *AnotherTask* :)

Comment: I cannot assume that the external library will not be bad coding neither ;) Sorry about that understatement. +1 for the partial solution